# Show that the determinant of the Hessian matrix of $f(x)=|x|^{\alpha}$, $\alpha>1$, is bounded away from zero when $1>|x|>c>0$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Let $\alpha>1$ and let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=|x|^{\alpha}$. Let  $$H(x):=\partial_{x_{i}}\partial_{x_{j}}f (x).$$

How can one show that there exists some $C>0$ such that $$\text{det}(H(x))\geq C$$ whenever $c_{2}>|x|>c_{1}>0$.

Write $H(x)=(h_{ij}(x))$, $1\leq i,j\leq n$. Direct calculations give
$$h_{ij}(x)=\alpha|x|^{\alpha-4}\begin{cases}
(\alpha-2)x^2_{i}+|x|^2,& i=j,\\\\ (\alpha-2)x_{i}x_{j},& i\neq j. \end{cases}$$

So, $H=\alpha|x|^{\alpha-4}(S+|x|^2 I_{n})$
where $S$ is the symmetric matrix $(\alpha-2)(x_i x_j)$. It is easy to show that $\text{det}(S)=0$.
Does this simplify the problem ?

Comment: If your hessian is exact, you should look for the eigenvalues of $S$. Then the eigenvalues of $S + |x|^2 I_n$ are $\lambda_i + |x|^2$ and you can easily obtain the determinant of $S + |x|^2 I_n$

Comment: How do the two equations $det(A-\lambda I)=$ and $det(B-\mu I)=0$ together imply that $det(A+B-(\lambda+\mu) I)=0$. Equivalently, how does the existence of two nonzero vectors $v$, $w$ such that $Av=\lambda v$ and $Bv=\mu v$ imply the existence of a nonzero vector $u$  such that $(A+B)u=(\lambda+\mu)u$ ?

Comment: No it is a property for $I_n$. If $Av=\lambda v$ then $(A+xI)v=\lambda v + xv$

Comment: Very nice. So $\text{det}(S+|x|^2 I_{n}) =(|x|^2+|x|^2)\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(0+|x|^2)=2|x|^{2n}$ which you obtain below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$rank(S)=1$ so $0$ is an eigenvalue of order $n-1$.

The last eigen value is given by $\lambda + (n-1)\times 0 = Tr(S)$ and $$\lambda = |x|^2$$

$S$ is equivalent to $diag(|x|^2,0,0,...0)$

And $S+|x|^2I_n$ is equivalent to $diag(2|x|^2,|x|^2,...|x|^2)$

Therefore $$det(S+|x|^2I_n)=2|x|^{2n}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are $ n \times n$ matrices, then $\det(A+B)$ is the sum of the detrminants of all the matrices that can be formed by taking $m$ rows from $A$ and $ n-m $ rows from $B$ as $m$ ranges from $0$ to $n$. In the case of $\det(S+\vert x \vert^2I_n)$, if two or more rows are taken from $S$ the detrminant is $0$. If one row is taken from $S$, the determinant is $\vert x \vert^{2(n-1)}(x_1^2+...+x_n^2)=\vert x \vert^{2n}$. If no rows are  taken from $S$ the determinant is $\vert x \vert^{2n}$. Thus the determinant of $S+\vert x \vert^2I_n$ is $2 \vert x \vert^{2n}$ so the determinant of the Hessian is $(\alpha \vert x \vert^{\alpha-4})^n2\vert x \vert^{2n}$. You can take it from there.

Comment: @Medo If you take 2 or more rows from $S$ the determinant is0. If  you take the $i$th row from $S$ and the oher$ n-1 $ rows from $\vert x \vert ^2I_n$ the determinant is $x_i^2\vert x \vert^{2(n-1)}$. Add up these determinants for $i=1,...,n$

Comment: Should the first line read  "the sum of the products of the determinants" ?